# Core 0 and Core 1 Arduino -- dont want to restart variables in Core 0

Tags: c++, esp32

I am using an ESP32 to control the movement of some motors. On the one hand, I am using the Core 0 of the microcontroller to command just the starting of the motors. On the other hand, the main code (Core 1) reads a message sent via serial port(S10;90;20;?), which defines the movement frequency of each motor. Then, these frequencies are written into three different variables(percentStp1 percentStp2, percentStp3) that the Core 0 interpretates and moves the motors. The problem is that once the programm of the Core 0 is executed the value of the frequency variables is reset to 0. I do not know why because, as far as I understand, the Core 0 also provides a loop and the variables should just be upgraded in case I send another command via the serial monitor (Also the flag is upgraded to 0...). I have define a flag and the variables are type "volatile" and still does not work... here you have the code:

```
 // STEPPER 
  int delaytime = 100;
  int StepNr = 0;
  String incomSting = "";
  char * pch; 
  
  int Stepper1Pin = 12;
  int Stepper2Pin = 14;
  int Stepper3Pin = 27;
  
  volatile int percentStp1 = 0;
  volatile int percentStp2 = 0;
  volatile int percentStp3 = 0;

  volatile int flag = 0;

  TaskHandle_t Task1;
  void Task1code(void * parameter) 
  {
    for(;;) 
    {

    while (flag == 1){
    //Run Steppers
    if(percentStp1 > StepNr)
    {
      digitalWrite(Stepper1Pin, HIGH);
     
    }
    if(percentStp2 > StepNr)
    {
      digitalWrite(Stepper2Pin, HIGH);
    }
    if(percentStp3 > StepNr)
    {
     digitalWrite(Stepper3Pin, HIGH);
    }  
   
    StepNr++; 
    delayMicroseconds(delaytime);
    digitalWrite(Stepper1Pin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Stepper2Pin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Stepper3Pin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(delaytime);

    Serial.println(percentStp1);
     
    if(StepNr > 100)
    { 
      StepNr = 0;
    }
 
  }
}
  }
void setup()
{
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println("Start"); 

//STEPPER
      xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(Task1code, "Task1", 10000, NULL, 0 , &Task1, 0); 
      pinMode(Stepper1Pin, OUTPUT); 
      pinMode(Stepper2Pin, OUTPUT); 
      pinMode(Stepper3Pin, OUTPUT); 
}


void loop() 
{

while(Serial.available() > 1)
    {
    incomSting = Serial.readStringUntil('?');// read the incoming data character by character
    } 

    
    char charBuf[incomSting.length() + 1];
    incomSting.toCharArray(charBuf, incomSting.length() + 1);
    
      if(charBuf[0]=='S')
      {
        charBuf[0]='0';
        Serial.println("Stepper");   
        pch = strtok(charBuf,";");
        sscanf(pch, "%d", &percentStp1);
        pch = strtok (NULL, ";");
        sscanf(pch, "%d", &percentStp2);
        pch = strtok (NULL, ";");
        sscanf(pch, "%d", &percentStp3);
        Serial.print("S1:"); 
        Serial.println(percentStp1); 
        Serial.print("S2:"); 
        Serial.println(percentStp2); 
        Serial.print("S3:"); 
        Serial.println(percentStp3); 
        incomSting = "";
        flag = 1;
      } 
}
```

Comment: How do you know the *percentStp* variables are reset to 0? How do you know it's related to the code run on core 0? More likely, your string parsing code doesn't get the data it expects and doesn't work properly. Do you understand the effect of the timeout of the `readStringUntil()` function?

Comment: Because I am using a serial.print to see how the value changes. And also because I have tried the hole code in the Core 1 before and it worked. The readStringUntil() is not a problem

Comment: You are using `Serial.print` after you have scanned a new value with `sscanf`. So `sscanf` or rather the string passed to `sscanf` is likely the problem. Additionally output the value passed to `sscanf` and show the full output so we can understand whether the value differs between the output from core 0 and core 1.